# Mulesoft API Designer auto load RAML file

Tags: raml

I can see how you can import/export zip files containing RAML files using API Designer.

I would like to give the URL of the API Designer to someone to view a RAML file that I have created.

Is there any way to automatically import a zip file (perhaps from a URL) into API Designer rather than having to send them a zip file and have them import it?

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no way to expose your RAML directly from the API Designer for someone to consume - that said, you need to expose it by yourself somewhere. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to import the RAML from a URL either, but that is a really good idea. I will file an issue for you.

https://github.com/mulesoft/api-designer/issues/366

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anypoint online instead of a local API Designer you can expose the RAML via a public or private API Portal.

Answer (score 0):

By Anypoint studio online you can expose your RAML as public API portal and RAML resources can access from there, also able to download your raml as zip from there.